# How can i make in blender a hollow cylinder but only from inside with a door as object for unity3d?

Tags: unity-game-engine, blender

I did this simple tutorial and it's making a cylinder hollow.
But i don't want it to be open from top and bottom i want it only to be hollow inside but to keep the cylinder closed.

Then i want to cut some kind of square/door so i can walk in later in unity3d with my character. The question is how to keep the cylinder hollow without making it open on top and bottom ? How to cut/make a door ? And how to save it as gameobject or whatever it needed to be able to use it in unity3d ?

[Cylinder hollow tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qIOpgKswi58)

Answer (score 0):

You can use boolean modifier with other square mesh or knife tool to make a hole in your mesh. Later you can export it to unity.